# RailsDB接続を外部で行う

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql

Ruby on Railsでは、DBのコネクションが最初にはられてしまうと思います。
database.ymlを複製したり、Connectionを手動で設定することで複数DBアクセスはできると思いますが、例えばWebサービスで複数人が違うDBを使う場合、コネクションクラスをRubyなどで外に出して、完全に制御することは可能ですか？
違うDBを利用する場合、動的に切り替えることにすると、コネクションが複雑なことになってしまうと思いますので、コネクションクラスを通して接続、DBの操作、コネクションを切断、という処理をしたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecordはRailsが必須なわけではなく、単体で使うこともできます。その場合、接続、切断は自分で操作することになります。その使い方で、手動で操作するI/Fを自分で作っても良いですし、`rails new`する時に`--skip-active-record`することで自動で管理される部分を無くすこともできます。

しかし、

> 例えばWebサービスで複数人が違うDBを使う場合

というのは「例えば」で取り上げられるような一般的なユースケースとは言えません。本当にそれが必要なのか再検討された方がいいとおもいます。